# DIVs, DOJO, vertical scrolling, and IE6

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6, vertical-scrolling

I know there's several questions on this already, but I cannot find a solution anywhere.

Basically, I have CSS styling the body to fullscreen with no scrolling. Within this are 2 divs, for sidebar (left) and content (will be a map control if I can get past this problem).

Within the left sidebar I have 2 divs (at the moment), one has a simple entry form for an address to search for (which can be set to a static height, 9ems or 100px), the second is intended to hold the results in a vertically scrolling list in the remaining space

I almost got there - IE 8, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera appeared all to be working fine - then, as our Corporate web team insist on IE6 compatibility (or at least the page should be usable), I tested it in IE6 - no scrollbars, and the list is extending beyond its parent div. Playing about a bit more with CSS, I get the scrollbar, but the div seems to be inheriting 100% height from the document.

So far I've been struggling for about 4 days with this, so any help or insight is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For situations where I absolutely really HAVE to support IE6, I use conditional comments to add extra HTML and CSS, and possibly hide other stuff. Making layouts for IE6, IMO, basically comes down to "whatever it takes" - ditch proper document structures, endulge in table-based layout, use spacer images, etc. etc. Especially sizes expressed as percentages are horribly broken in IE6 - whoever implemented them apparently didn't have the faintest idea what they were supposed to mean.